# Bind HTML tag to data or prop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Is it possible to bind an HTML tag (element) to the value of a data or property in Vue 2?

I tried different syntaxes but couldn't get any to work, and googling didn't help.

Here are two of the syntaxes I tried:

Direct 'string' interpolation:

```
<{{ someProp ? 'button' : 'a' }}>
    <!-- Some complex template I want to keep DRY -->
</{{ someProp ? 'button' : 'a' }}>
```

v-bind the tag on a template element (hopeful guess):

```
<template :tag="someProp ? 'button' : 'a'">
    <!-- Some complex template I want to keep DRY -->
</template >
```

If that's not possible, how can I avoid duplicating the content and attributes of the element just to change the associated HTML tag? What I want to avoid is:

```
<button v-if="someProp" /* Some attribute bindings */>
    <!-- Some complex template I want to keep DRY -->
</button>
<a v-else /* Repeating the above attribute bindings */>
    <!-- Repeating the above template, breaking the DRY principle -->
</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dynamic [component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#component) tag in Vue is intended to work with Vue components, but it does work with HTML tags as well.

```
<component :is="tag">Click me</component>
```

Here is an example.

```js
console.clear()


new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    tag: "a",
  },
  methods:{
    onClick(){
      alert('clicked')
    },
    changeTag(){
      this.tag = this.tag == "a" ? "button" : "a"
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <component :is="tag" @click="onClick" href="javascript:void(0)">Click me</component>

  <hr>
  <button @click="changeTag">Change tag</button>
</div>
```